# Creating new column in panda with data based on multiple percentile conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to create a new column in my dataframe which indicates yes or no based on percentiles. Basically, it should input 'yes' in the new column df['ideal_weight'] if the data in the df.fats column is between 25th to 50th percentile. thank you.

```
df['ideal_weight'] = np.where((df.fats > np.percentile(df.fats, 25) & df.fats < np.percentile(df.fats, 50)), 'yes', 'no')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is actually fine in theory; you're just missing parentheses:

```
df['ideal_weight'] = np.where(((df.fats > np.percentile(df.fats, 25)) & (df.fats < np.percentile(df.fats, 50))), 'yes', 'no')
```